# Two SQL queries and pass each as a dataset to pass as parameters

Tags: sql, powershell, parameters, dataset

Im very new to Powershell and I've scraped together the following code for a script that will check for an 'old' folder and create it if not found.  It will then move the compressed weblogs from current location to the 'old' folder.  I am wanting this written to pull the server names and website names from a sql query so it can be setup to run nightly and does not need to be updated with new or deleted servers.  I have the following written so far but since I'm new I cannot figure out the last bit of syntax.

```
clear
$SqlServer = "SERVER"
$SqlCatalog = "DATABASE"
$SqlQuery = "select hsa.servername from SERVER.dbo.serversapp hsa
inner join SERVER.dbo.apphosts hah on hsa.vchservername = hah.vchservername
where hsa.tirecordstatus = 1
order by hsa.vchservername desc"
$SqlQuery1 = "select hah.vchhost from SERVER.dbo.serversapp hsa
inner join SERVER.dbo.apphosts hah on hsa.vchservername = hah.vchservername
where hsa.tirecordstatus = 1
order by hsa.vchservername desc"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SqlServer; Database = $SqlCatalog; Integrated Security = True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0]
```

What I would like to do is have each $SQLQuery run and store each one in it's own dataset table so I can pass each one as a parameter for the following code.  What I need to figure out is:

1)How do I write the above to run both SQL queries and have each one be either it's own dataset or table so I can them as parameters; $Servername and $HostedGroup?

2)How do I set this up to recurse the below code on each of the servers from the $Servername parameter?

```
$Servername = Dataset1
$Hostedgroup = Dataset2
$OldFolder = "\\$Servername\C$\Ren\Weblogs\$Hostedgroup\old"
$FolderExists = Test-Path $OldFolder


if($FolderExists -eq $False)
{
new-item \\$Servername\C$\Ren\Weblogs\$Hostedgroup\old -type directory
}
then
{
if(Test-Path \\$Servername\C$\Ren\Weblogs\old\W3SVC2)
{
get-childitem -path '\\$Servername\C$\Ren\WebLogs\$Hostedgroup\W3SVC2' -recurse -include *.zip | move-item -destination '\\$Servername\C$\Ren\WebLogs\$Hostedgroup\old'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)` returns an integer; you should prevent your script/function from returning it by assigning it to `$null` or using `Out-Null`. (e.g. `$null = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)`)

For the answer to your question, you can return both fields from a single query, then iterate over the results. The pattern would look like this:

```
function Get-HostedServerApp {
    $SqlServer = "SERVER"
    $SqlCatalog = "DATABASE"
    $SqlQuery = @"
select hsa.vchappservername, hah.vchhost 
from SERVER.dbo.hostedserversapp hsa
inner join SERVER.dbo.hostedapphosts hah on hsa.vchappservername = hah.vchappservername
where hsa.tirecordstatus = 1
order by hsa.vchappservername desc
"@
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SqlServer; Database = $SqlCatalog; Integrated Security = True"
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $null = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $SqlConnection.Close()
    $Dataset.Tables[0]
}

# Place your logic in this function
function SomeFunction {
    param(
    $Servername,
    $Hostedgroup
    )

    "\\$Servername\C`$\Renaissance\Weblogs\$Hostedgroup\old"
}

$data = Get-HostedServerApp

$data| foreach{SomeFunction -ServerName $_.vchappservername -HostedGroup $_.vchhost}
```

Comment: I did. On the last line of the example, the records returned from `Get-HostedServerApp` are passed to the `foreach` CmdLet (full name is `ForEach-Object`). `Foreach` executes the scriptblock for each object that is passed down the pipeline. See `help ForEach-Object -Online` for more info.

Comment: `\\$Servername\C`$\Renaissance\Weblogs\$Hostedgroup\old` is merely added as a placeholder for your code. In the comment above the function, I wrote: `# Place your logic in this function`

Comment: So with your function, I no longer need these parameters: $Servername = Dataset1<--------------- $Hostedgroup = Dataset2<--------------

Comment: Well, the parameters have been moved to the `SomeFunction` (feel free to replace with your own name) function, and the values are passed to them on the last line of the script. But yes, you would paste everything from your second example except for those two lines  into `SomeFunction` in place of `"\\$Servername\C`$\Renaissance\Weblogs\$Hostedgroup\old"`. I didn't place your code into my answer since I don't have the same setup as you, and am unable to test it. I would run `move-item` with the `-WhatIf` parameter to make sure it does what you want.